# How to change utf-8 to cp932 by python with django framework?

Tags: python, django, utf-8, encode

python: 2.7.3

django: 1.3.1

```
#:coding=utf-8:

import csv
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
from task.models import Task

def export_history_templates(output, encoding='cp932'):
    header = [ 
        u'ID',
        u'NAME',
        u'SENDER',
    ]   
    header = [s.encode(encoding) for s in header]

    writer = csv.writer(output)
    writer.writerow(header)

    for t in Task.objects.order_by('-id'):
        r = [ 
            t.id,
            smart_str(t.name, encoding=encoding),
            smart_str(t.user, encoding=encoding),  # user is a User table object
        ]   
        writer.writerow(r)
```

This is a csv download method.After I generate a csv file.I can see the `user` data by utf-8 encode rightly,but can't in shift_jis(converted `cp932`) rightly.

Why and how to do?

Comment: Can you give us some example? Why do you say it still is in `utf-8`?

Comment: I have added the source.

Comment: what exactly is the result you get?

Comment: When I open the csv file.I can see the `NAME(t.name)` rightly,but the `SENDER(t.user)` is garbled.

Comment: Does `user` has defined the  method `__unicode__`. `t.name` is probably showing well because it is a CharField but user is a `User` so you'll be better off doing `smart_str(unicode(t.user), encoding=encoding)`. Also it will help to see some output examples.

Comment: @PauloBu `user` has not defined the method `__unicode__`.When I use `smart_str(unicode(t.user), encoding=encoding)`,it works for me!Thank you very much!Could you write an answer below?I give you some reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to convert the `user` instance to Unicode like this:

```
smart_str(unicode(t.user), encoding=encoding)
```

Hope this works!